# Помочь рассчитать длину в px и поправить границы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

1. Есть следующее: нужно, чтобы полоска при нажатии на год вставала ровно (к примеру если нажать на 1967 - она встанет ровно), но если нажимать далее, то она всё дальше и дальше уходит.
2. Второй баг - это, если нажимать на сам бегунок, то как только он достигает последнего года (2008), то он не останавливается, если снова на него нажать, то он уйдет и дальше - помогите сделать так, чтоб когда бегунок стоял на 2008 году и при нажатии на него всё сбрасывалось в 1967 год (то есть назад).

```js
var current_num = 0; //текущая позиция

$('.breakpoint').click(function(e) { //при нажатии на год перемещаем к нему
  var num = $('#timeline .breakpoint').index(this); //выясняем, на какой год нажали
  move_to_num(num);
});

$('.roller').click(function(e) { // при клике по поезду перемещаем вперёд
  var num = current_num + 1; //увеличиваем текущую позицию на 1
  move_to_num(num);
});

function move_to_num(num) {
  if (num != current_num) { //перемещаем только если нажали не на текущий год
    $('#timeline .breakpoint').eq(current_num).removeClass('current'); //убираем у предыдущего стиль выбранного
    current_num = num; //сохраняем в текущую позицию

    $('#timeline .breakpoint').eq(current_num).addClass('current'); //назначаем текущему стиль выбранного
    // $('#timeline').css('margin-left', -(num-1)*300); //сдвигаем таймлан на текущую точку*ширину элемента влево
    $('.roller').css('left', num * 206 + 100); //сдвигаем паровозик соотвтетственно вправо
  }
}
```

```css
#timeline {
  top: 327px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: margin-left 1s ease .5s;
  transition: margin-left 1s ease .5s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #45dae0;
}

.breakpoint {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85px;
  margin-left: 82px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 220px;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: DinProLight, sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.breakpoint span {
  position: relative;
  left: -19px;
}

.breakpoint span:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #4b4b4b;
  top: -26px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.breakpoint span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 96px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #666;
  top: -121px;
  left: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.breakpoint.first-item {
  margin-left: 56px;
}

.breakpoint.current,
.breakpoint:hover {
  color: #009da9;
}

.breakpoint.current span:before,
.breakpoint:hover span:before {
  background-color: #00c0cc;
  z-index: 1;
}

.breakpoint.current span:after,
.breakpoint:hover span:after {
  background-color: #00c0cc;
}

.lines {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 104px;
}

.lines:before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 77px;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
  position: absolute;
}

.lines:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 58px;
  bottom: -57px;
  left: 58px;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  position: absolute;
}

.light-lines {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 104px;
}

.light-lines:before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 58px;
  bottom: -57px;
  left: -1px;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  position: absolute;
}

.light-lines:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 58px;
  bottom: -57px;
  left: 85px;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  position: absolute;
}

.main-lines {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 104px;
}

.main-lines:before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 77px;
  top: 0;
  left: 42px;
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
  position: absolute;
}

.roller {
  -webkit-transition: left 1s ease .5s;
  transition: left 1s ease .5s;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 358px;
  top: -383px;
  left: 135px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}

.roller:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #009eab;
  width: 1px;
  height: 355px;
}

.roller:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: -16px;
  width: 5px;
  left: -9px;
  height: 5px;
  border: 7px solid #00c0cc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2.5px;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

.roller .for-arrow {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: -41px;
  left: -21px;
}

.roller .for-arrow img {
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timeline">
  <div class="roller">
    <span class="rol-elem"></span>
    <div class="for-arrow">
      <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="arrow">
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint first-item current">1963 <span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">1967<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">1987<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">1992<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">1996<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">1998<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">2000<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">2001<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">2003<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">2008<span class="dot"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я к сожалению так и не смог понять, как мне выравнять по пиксельные отступы, в примере вашем изначально бегунок стоит не на месте, а чем дальше едет - тем всё дальше отрывается от заданной точки.

Comment: Смотрел на маке в трех браузерах и картина была как раз обратная. В моем примере по шкале было ровно, а в вашем нет.

Comment: Обновил свой ответ полностью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переделал еще раз полностью.

Я стараюсь выбирать при верстке ровные значения, если это возможно. Как раз в таких случаях, как в вашем примере, это помогает в дальнейших расчетах.

Одно деление шкалы у меня равно 50px. Расстояние между годами соответственно 200px.

Наверняка вам придется еще поработать над деталями, т.к. я не имею полной картины.

```js
function timeline() {
  var $timeline = $('#timeline'), // кэшируем контейнер
    $year = $('.breakpoint'), // кэшируем год
    current_num = 0, // текущая позиция
    max_num = $year.length - 1; // максимальное количество лет (минус один, т.к. отсчет идет с нуля)

  // устанавливаем ширину контейнеру (50 - это ширина одного деления шкалы в пикселях, 200 - ширина четырех)
  $timeline.width(max_num * 200 + 50);

  $year.click(function() { // при нажатии на год перемещаем к нему
    var num = $timeline.find('.breakpoint').index(this); // выясняем, на какой год нажали

    move_to_num(num);
  });

  $('.roller').click(function() { // при клике по поезду перемещаем вперёд
    var num = current_num;

    if (num === max_num) {
      num = 0; // текущий год - это последний год, сбрасываем счетчик
    } else {
      num += 1; // увеличиваем текущую позицию на 1
    }

    move_to_num(num);
  });

  function move_to_num(num) {
    if (num !== current_num) { // перемещаем только если нажали не на текущий год
      $timeline.find('.breakpoint').eq(current_num).removeClass('current'); // убираем у предыдущего стиль выбранного
      current_num = num; // обновляем текущую позицию

      $timeline.find('.breakpoint').eq(current_num).addClass('current'); // назначаем текущему стиль выбранного

      // сдвигаем таймлайн, если необходимо (200 - это ширина между годами (4 деления по 50))
      if (num === 0) {
        $timeline.css('margin-left', -(num) * 200);
      } else if (num === max_num) {
        $timeline.css('margin-left', -(num - 2) * 200);
      } else {
        $timeline.css('margin-left', -(num - 1) * 200);
      }

      $('.roller').css('left', num * 200); // сдвигаем паровозик
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  timeline();
});
```

```css
#timeline-container {
  height: 260px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#timeline {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #45dae0;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transition: margin-left 1s ease .5s;
}

.line {
  float: left;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
}

.line:before,
.line:after {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.line-small:before,
.line-big:before {
  left: 25px;
  width: 1px;
}

.line-small:before {
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  height: 60px;
}

.line-big:before {
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
  height: 75px;
}

.breakpoint {
  cursor: pointer;
  font: 19px DinProLight, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.breakpoint span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  bottom: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

.breakpoint:before,
.breakpoint:after {
  background-color: #4b4b4b;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.breakpoint:before {
  height: 100px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 1px;
}

.breakpoint:after {
  bottom: -3px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 23px;
  width: 5px;
}

.breakpoint.current,
.breakpoint:hover {
  color: #009da9;
}

.breakpoint:hover:before,
.breakpoint:hover:after,
.breakpoint.current:before,
.breakpoint.current:after {
  background-color: #009da9;
}

.roller {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 1s ease .5s;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.roller:before,
.roller:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.roller:before {
  background-color: #009eab;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 25px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 1px;
}

.roller:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 7px solid #00c0cc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 5px;
  left: 15px;
  height: 5px;
}

.rol-elem {
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
  left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="timeline-container">
  <div id="timeline">
    <div class="roller">
      <div class="rol-elem"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line breakpoint current">
      <span>1963</span>
    </div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line line-big"></div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line breakpoint">
      <span>1967</span>
    </div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line line-big"></div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line breakpoint">
      <span>1987</span>
    </div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line line-big"></div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line breakpoint">
      <span>1992</span>
    </div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line line-big"></div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line breakpoint">
      <span>1996</span>
    </div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line line-big"></div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line breakpoint">
      <span>1998</span>
    </div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line line-big"></div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line breakpoint">
      <span>2000</span>
    </div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line line-big"></div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line breakpoint">
      <span>2001</span>
    </div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line line-big"></div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line breakpoint">
      <span>2003</span>
    </div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line line-big"></div>
    <div class="line line-small"></div>
    <div class="line breakpoint">
      <span>2008</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. У вас лишние цифры при расчете положения через `left`. Намного легче выставить первоначальное положение в css, например, через `transform:translate()`, и уже от этого "плясать". Сейчас расстояние между линиями `.breakpoint` - `176px`. Это число и умножайте на ваш `num`. И проверьте расстояние между 1996 и 1998 годами - там у вас где-то 1 пиксель теряется.
2. Нужно проверять `num` на кол-во всех `.breakpoint`. Если `num` > кол-ва `.breakpoint`, ставим `num = 0`, и `.roller` переходит на первую позицию.
   Ну, и переменную `num` нужно сделать глобальной, чтобы она менялась при любом клике - как на `.roller`, так и на `.breakpoint`.

```js
var current_num = 0; //текущая позиция
var num = 0;
$('.breakpoint').click(function(e) { //при нажатии на год перемещаем к нему
  num = $('#timeline .breakpoint').index(this); //выясняем, на какой год нажали
  move_to_num(num);
});

$('.roller').click(function(e) { // при клике по поезду перемещаем вперёд
  num = current_num + 1; //увеличиваем текущую позицию на 1
  if (num > $('.breakpoint').length - 1) {
    num = 0
  }
  move_to_num(num);
});

function move_to_num(num) {
  if (num != current_num) { //перемещаем только если нажали не на текущий год
    $('#timeline .breakpoint').eq(current_num).removeClass('current'); //убираем у предыдущего стиль выбранного
    current_num = num; //сохраняем в текущую позицию

    $('#timeline .breakpoint').eq(current_num).addClass('current'); //назначаем текущему стиль выбранного
    // $('#timeline').css('margin-left', -(num-1)*300); //сдвигаем таймлан на текущую точку*ширину элемента влево
    $('.roller').css('left', num * 176); //сдвигаем паровозик соотвтетственно вправо
  }
}
```

```css
#timeline {
  top: 327px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: margin-left 1s ease .5s;
  transition: margin-left 1s ease .5s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #45dae0;
}

.breakpoint {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85px;
  margin-left: 82px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 220px;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: DinProLight, sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.breakpoint span {
  position: relative;
  left: -19px;
}

.breakpoint span:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #4b4b4b;
  top: -26px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.breakpoint span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 96px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #666;
  top: -121px;
  left: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.breakpoint.first-item {
  margin-left: 56px;
}

.breakpoint.current,
.breakpoint:hover {
  color: #009da9;
}

.breakpoint.current span:before,
.breakpoint:hover span:before {
  background-color: #00c0cc;
  z-index: 1;
}

.breakpoint.current span:after,
.breakpoint:hover span:after {
  background-color: #00c0cc;
}

.lines {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 104px;
}

.lines:before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 77px;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
  position: absolute;
}

.lines:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 58px;
  bottom: -57px;
  left: 58px;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  position: absolute;
}

.light-lines {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 104px;
}

.light-lines:before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 58px;
  bottom: -57px;
  left: -1px;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  position: absolute;
}

.light-lines:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 58px;
  bottom: -57px;
  left: 85px;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  position: absolute;
}

.main-lines {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 104px;
}

.main-lines:before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 77px;
  top: 0;
  left: 42px;
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
  position: absolute;
}

.roller {
  -webkit-transition: left 1s ease .5s;
  transition: left 1s ease .5s;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 358px;
  top: -383px;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translate(141px, 0);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}

.roller:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #009eab;
  width: 1px;
  height: 355px;
}

.roller:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: -16px;
  width: 5px;
  left: -9px;
  height: 5px;
  border: 7px solid #00c0cc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2.5px;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

.roller .for-arrow {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: -41px;
  left: -21px;
}

.roller .for-arrow img {
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timeline">
  <div class="roller">
    <span class="rol-elem"></span>
    <div class="for-arrow">
      <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="arrow">
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint first-item current">1963 <span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">1967<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">1987<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">1992<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">1996<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">1998<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">2000<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">2001<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">2003<span class="dot"></span></div>
  <span class="main-lines"></span>
  <span class="light-lines"></span>
  <div class="breakpoint">2008<span class="dot"></span></div>
</div>
```